# index.html index.php redirection + Internal Server Error

Tags: php, html, indexing, redirect

I'm using a mac, FTP is with Transmit.
I am doing a website for a client on Wordpress. The site is finished but my client wanted to add another page in front of the website so when you click on the URL in Google, you have a page with their logo which you click and then access to the wordpress website.

So : I created a index.html with dreamweaver pointing to "http://www...." and I uploaded it in the FTP. The index.php of the wordpress site points also to that same address.

I added this code here in the .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

I then had to replace the index.html by another one (same but the content image is just bigger to have full width) and removing the old one. And now nothing seems to point, or there a duplicate problem! I have the "Internal Server Problem, error 500".

So there, the word is out!
Thank You!

Comment: Just so you know, we call those sorts of things "splash pages," and they're generally accepted to be a [bad idea](http://www.bing.com/search?q=splash+pages+bad+idea&form=APMCS1). It may be worth trying to convince the client not to do it.

Comment: ya, you should definitely point out the usability issue's to your client.

Comment: All right. I thought so myself... so does anyone have an idea of how I can put it back the way it was? Meaning, do I just delete the index.html and write in the .htaccess : DirectoryIndex index.php ??

Comment: how do I put it back the way it was?

Comment: You can simply remove the line with the directory index (or comment it out using # at the beginning of the line) and you should also remove the index.html file (or rename it to something like index_old.html)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is wrong is hard to tell without knowing the error. If you have access to any apache log files, the error.log will tell you why it's outputting an error.

A HTTP 500 status can be any kind of error, but in my experience it is most commonly due to:

- Incorrect file permissions on some files
- syntax error in the .htaccess file or httpd.conf (which I'm guessing you don't have access to)

If you are on a shared host and you do not have access to the apache error.log file or you don't know where it is, it would probably be a good idea to contact the sys admin or support and ask why you're getting the error or ask where you can find the error.log file

Comment: I've read everywhere that you can find what's wrong from the apache error.log but I have no idea where to access them. In my log file for example its only access.log.05 or any number... Thank you for your time!

Comment: Then you might have to contact the system administrator / support to find out what the error is. It might even be that they've disabled overriding the DirectoryIndex directive. That could cause a 500 error.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much, I think I'll do that!